# Using Fluent in a Vapor Command

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

I'm trying to use Fluent in a Command and I have this problem:

On this query:

```
let location: Location? = try? Location.query(on: context.application.db).filter(\.geId == 123).first().wait()
```

I get:
`Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"`

---

When I remove the filter, everything is fine:

```
let location: Location? = try? Location.query(on: context.application.db).first().wait()
```

---

When I make the var non optional:

```
let location: Location = try? Location.query(on: context.application.db).filter(\.geId == 123).first().wait()
```

I get:
`Cannot convert value of type 'Location?' to specified type 'Location'`

The same query is working on a Route with **flatMap** instead of the **wait()**

So, I'm a bit confused. Where ist my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a simple one...
Just missing the

```
import Fluent
```

Thanks to @0xTim at Discord :)